# Snowball Question FFT

Tags: algorithms, fourier-transform, polynomials

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/prac-quiz2-sol.pdf

I'm confused as to the solution for the snowball question. To start with, I have two specific questions:

(1) Each pair $a_i,b_j$ will account for one term (and why ONE term)? What is meant by term here? The coefficient, $c_k$ of the polynomial C? Or maybe the $x$ value at the $kth$ spot?

(2) Why is $c_k$ the number of such pairs?

Comment: Could you copy the relevant information into the question (with attribution of course!) to make the question as self-contained as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea of the proof. Let $a_i,b_i$ be the distance thrown by the $i$th male/female. Using FFT, we calculate
$$ \left(\sum_i x^{a_i}\right) \left(\sum_j x^{b_j}\right) = \sum_{i,j} x^{a_i+b_j}. $$
Each pair $i,j$ satisfying $a_i + b_j = k$ contributes one term $x^k$ to the polynomial on the right. Hence the coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of pairs $i,j$ such that $a_i + b_j = k$.

If things still aren't clear, I suggest you try a few examples.

Comment: First you didn't even try to answer my specific questions. And now we have 3 summation signs, where there were none in the solution. So I am now more confused.

Comment: Moreover, what is $x^k$? Is it a coefficient?

Comment: Finally, you need an argument to go from Each pair i,j satisfying $a_i+b_j=k$ contributes one term $x^k$ to the polynomial on the right. To the claim that the coefficient of $x^k$ = number of pairs that equal $k$

Comment: Here $x^k$ is a monomial ($x$ is known as a "formal variable"). You can also think of it as a polynomial having a single monomial. I suggest you go over the FFT algorithm again - they must have covered polynomials when they discussed the algorithm, especially given the application to multiplying univariate polynomials.

Comment: Re your other comment, I agree that an argument is required, but only if you want to be very formal. Otherwise, I suggest you try a few examples and see how it works.

Comment: The key seems to be that the x^a and x^b have coefficients of 1; else coefficient of x^k wouldn't count the number of pairs where a_i + b_j = k.